# Map function str to list of class instance variables

Tags: python

I have a class with several properties. I want just the values for each property to be on one line each.

I tried using map however it is pointing to the instance of each class (`<task_Backlog_Puller.Case object at 0x7ff2018f0240>`) in the list and I need to get the values of each of the class properties. I cannot import libraries from 3rd party.

```
class Case:
    def __init__(self, case_number, owner, title, status, priority, date_created):
        self.case_number = case_number
        self.owner = owner
        self.title = title
        self.status = status
        self.priority = priority
        self.date_created = date_created




def create_report_of_cases_older_than_30_days(total_number_of_all_cases, number_of_cases_older_than_30_days, cases_older_than_30_days):
    report = "Total number of cases in team backlog is " + str(total_number_of_all_cases) + '\n'
    report += "Total number of cases older than 30 days is " + str(number_of_cases_older_than_30_days) + '\n'
    report += '\n'
    report += '\n'.join(map(str, cases_older_than_30_days))
    logger.info("Report -> {}".format(report))
    return str(report)
```

---

```
2017-07-06 18:27:00,422 [    INFO] task_Backlog_Puller.116 --- Report -> Total number of cases in team backlog is 17
Total number of cases older than 30 days is 9

<task_Backlog_Puller.Case object at 0x7ff2018f0240>
<task_Backlog_Puller.Case object at 0x7ff202540a20>
<task_Backlog_Puller.Case object at 0x7ff1fe3b45f8>
<task_Backlog_Puller.Case object at 0x7ff20043ee80>
<task_Backlog_Puller.Case object at 0x7ff20043ee10>
<task_Backlog_Puller.Case object at 0x7ff2018d16a0>
<task_Backlog_Puller.Case object at 0x7ff2018d1cf8>
<task_Backlog_Puller.Case object at 0x7ff2018d1a58>
<task_Backlog_Puller.Case object at 0x7ff2018d1e80>
```

Comment: Implement the `__str__` magic method.

Comment: Do you actually plan on having any methods in your `Case` class? If this is the case, and it is acting as a sort of record, you'd be better served by using a `namedtuple`

Comment: No methods or functions just DTO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to control how a python class is cast to string, you can define a `__str__` function in the class definition.

```
class Case:
    def __init__(self, case_number, owner, title, status, priority, date_created):
        self.case_number = case_number
        self.owner = owner
        self.title = title
        self.status = status
        self.priority = priority
        self.date_created = date_created

    def __str__(self):
        return # create a string here based on the properties of self

str(case) # will call case.__str__()
```

Comment: It may also be a good idea to assign `__repr__` to `__str__` so the custom format will be called for all cases.